# jQuery's ajaxStart

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using such construction:

```
$('#wait').ajaxStart(function() {
    if ($(this).not(':visible'))
        $(this).showWarning();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
        $(this).hideWarning();
}).ajaxError(function() {
    alert('Unexpected error...');
});
```

And I want to disable submit button every time the user clicks on it. In order to make it universal - I want to do it in ajaxStart method, so is there any way to get the button's id which initialized the request?
Thank you

Comment: you can use global variable to hold ID of button and use it in ajaxStart function.

Comment: Can u pass the button click event to the function ?

Comment: @sub_stantial: what do you mean? To which function should I pass the button click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all of your submit button a class, for example: `submitBtn`, then

```
$('.submitBtn').ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can pass the button click event to the function here, you can do it like this :

```
$('#wait').ajaxSend(function(event) {        //pass event object
  $(event.target).css('disabled','disabled');   //get event target
  if ($(this).not(':visible'))
        $(this).showWarning();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
        $(this).hideWarning();
}).ajaxError(function() {
    alert('Unexpected error...');
});
```

Comment: According to jQuery's manual (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) the callback function does not receives any parameters

Comment: My mistake, it should be ajaxSend and not ajaxStart. You can pass events to ajaxSend, check it out here http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Comment: Actually, ajaxStart works fine with parameters, but its target field refers to $('#wait') and not to initial button

Comment: what does event.target returns you ?

Comment: $('#wait') - the parent div or the source.. I don't know how to call it

Comment: ok let me try something, I will let you know if I find an alternative to achieve this.

Comment: I think there is no way to implement it. It is neccessary to add such code to each ajaz request.