# Ajax start event issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Im trying to show a progressbar when my page is doing an ajax request.

I have a div with an image inside it and i would like to show it on the ajaxStart event. The problem is the img only shows itself when the ajaxStart event is done. However the alert is fired before the ajax request.

```
         $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            alert("test");

            document.getElementById('LoadingDiv').style.visibility = "visible";

        });
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you make the AJAX call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery's ajaxStart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005624/jquerys-ajaxstart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                            $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            async: true,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
```

Posted abit to early changed async to true and works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide loading spinner like this:

```
/*LOADING SPINNER*/
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loadingDiv').show()
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loadingDiv').hide()
  },
  success: function() {}
});
```

The `#loadingDiv` simply contains an animated image. The `ajaxSetup` method set default values for future Ajax requests.
That means that this loading indicator will be shown every time when making `ajax` calls.